# Mathematical notation in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, starting at $1$, is $$\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}.$$

Would this translate to...

For any $n$ a natural number, starting at $1$, the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers implies the equation?

Is it OK to assume that it's for all $n$? Or would that be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"Yes", except that the formula given is the sum of the **squares** of the natural numbers, from 1 to n.

Comment: Where does it say square?

Comment: It doesn't. But that's what that formula corresponds to. As written, it is wrong.  If "squares of the" is inserted between "the" and "first", it would be a correct statement.

Comment: It doesn't, but it *should*.

Comment: It doesn't mean n = 5, then 5+4+3+2+1 = 15?

Comment: It does, but: $\dfrac{5(5+1)(2\cdot 5+1)}{6}=55 = 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2$

Comment: If n=5, then $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2 = 5*(5+1)*(2*5+1)/6 = 55$

Comment: Ah. But in this case, please correct me if i'm wrong, it's saying the sum of the first n natural numbers implies the the sum of squares? Which is obviously false. So would it be right to disprove this?

Comment: There is a mistake in the statement of the formula.  Whoever write it forgot to put in "square".  That;'s really all there is to it.

Comment: No... It was written like that LOL. For sure it's not wrong. So this equation obviously is not correct, meaning I should disprove it right?

Comment: Well, as written you can disprove it with a counterexample. Your n=5 calculation is sufficient to do that.  n=2 is even simpler and also provides a counterexample.

Comment: Is it good enough to disprove this by providing a counter example?

Comment: Thank you sir! I hope you have a great day.

Comment: A counterexample is sufficient to disprove it.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect.   It should be the sum *for the squares of* the first $n$ non-zero natural numbers equals that.
$${\sum_{k=1}^n k =\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2!}\\\bbox[1ex, border:pink solid 1pt]{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 =\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3!}}\\\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 =\dfrac{6n^2(n+1)^2}{4!}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that? But more importantly: have you tried to derive the equation yourself?

The sum of the first two natural numbers is 3. The sum of the first three natural numbers is 6. The sum of the first four natural numbers is 10. The sum of the first five natural numbers is 15. Hmm, that looks like the triangular numbers.

If you look these up in the OEIS, you will verify that $$\binom{n + 1}{2} = \frac{n^2 + n}{2} = \sum_{i = 1}^n i.$$

None of those look like the formula you copied. Compute $$\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} = \frac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6}$$ for a few $n$, say $0 < n < 8$ and look that up in the OEIS: the square pyramidal numbers should be the very first result, and indeed we see that $$\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} = \sum_{i = 1}^n i^2.$$ That superscript 2 makes a big difference in the summation — does that count as a pun?

---

In both summations above you can substitute $i = 0$ and that won't change the result.

Comment: What are you showing here? I'm confused.

Comment: What are you confused by? The sigma notation? This explains that: http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/summation.html